# LWC datatable shows blank even though data is printed properly under <p> in html

Tags: lightning-datatable, lwc-wire-adapter

My question may be naive as I am new to this area. I need to show all object names list in LWC for which I have written one apex class which returns list of strings as object names. Even though teh list is showing properly in JS, it is not showing data under lightning-datatable in html. Any suggestion?

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
            Set<String> standardObjects = new Set<String>();
            for(Schema.SObjectType d : gd.values()){
                Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ds = d.getDescribe();
                if(!ds.isCreateable()){
                    continue;
                }
                if(ds.isCustom() == false && ds.getRecordTypeInfos().size() > 0){
                    standardObjects.add(ds.getName());
                }
            }
```

In JS, I have used an array to hold all objects and use it as data property of lightning-datatatble in html. I am clueless about keeping the fieldName property of field so I used 'Name'.

JS -

```
@wire(getAllStandardObjects)
    allStdObjs(result){
        if(result.data){
            this.allStdObjs = [];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                var item = {
                    id: i,
                    objectName: result.data[i],
                };
                this.allStdObjs.push(item);

                console.log('std obj list came:'+this.allStdObjs[i].objectName);
            }
            this.error = undefined;
        }else if(result.error){
            this.error = result.error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }
@track columns = [
        {
            label : 'Name', 
            fieldName : 'name',
            type : 'text'
        },
        {
            label : 'Action', 
            fieldName : 'action',
            type:'button',
            fixedWidth: 150,
            typeAttributes: {
                label: 'Show Fields',
                name: 'showfields',
                variant: 'brand'
            }
        }
    ];
```

HTML -

```
<lightning-datatable 
                            class="slds-border_top"
                            key-field="id"
                            columns={columns}
                            data={allStdObjs}
                            default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
                            sorted-direction={sortDirection}
                            sorted-by={sortedBy}
                            onsort={onHandleSort}>
                        </lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: I highly recommend you work abbreviations out of your coding habits. They make code much harder to read without making it particularly easier to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
{
    label : 'Name', 
    fieldName : 'name',
    type : 'text'
},
```

to this:

```
{
    label : 'Name', 
    fieldName : 'objectName',
    type : 'text'
},
```

That is the field name you are using here:

```
var item = {
    id: i,
    objectName: result.data[i],
};
```

Comment: @https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/1068/andres-perez, This works like magic. Thank you.